# To find out if 3 vectors are coplanar or not

Tags: vectors

3 vectors A,B and C are given. We have to find out if they are coplanar. I have been taught to find the cross product of any two of the 3 vector like B×C. This cross product will be perpendicular to both B and C. If A is coplanar to B and C then it will also be perpendicular to A. So if we find the dot product of A and (B×C) and if the product is 0 then it is coplanar because cos90 is 0. But what if A and B are coplanar but C is not. And we find the cross product of B and C which is (B×C) and it is perpendicular to both B and C. If it is perpendicular to B, it is also perpendicular to A so dot product of A and (B×C) will be 0 and we will think it means all of the 3 vectors are coplanar but it is only because B and A are coplanar and not C.Can someone respond to this dobut of mine? If my doubt is correct or is there some mistake I made?

Comment: Hint: Two vectors are always co-planar.